# no binary file given when building and unknown error below

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, clang, llvm-clang

ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Comment: the error is not unknown, it's telling you to see the error. However it is telling you that you don't have the appropriate linker architecture tooling installed (-v would explain it)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592445/ld-unsupported-tapi-file-type-tapi-tbd-in-yaml-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592445/ld-unsupported-tapi-file-type-tapi-tbd-in-yaml-file)