# Error when running a python file (unable to import psycopg2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I have a python script, and keep running into an error when trying to install a package.

I'm using pip 20.2.4 and python 3.7.7, on a MacOS Pro Catalina 10.15.7.

When I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it gets the below error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for psycopg2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psycopg2, psycopg2-binary
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/me/IdeaProjects/up/grafana/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/tv/xmlxs5hd45s0n4r0qs5jtlhnbgpkgq/T/pip-install-z1c97jsm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/tv/xmlxs5hd45s0n4r0qs5jtlhnbgpkgq/T/pip-install-z1c97jsm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/tv/xmlxs5hd45s0n4r0qs5jtlhnbgpkgq/T/pip-record-984vc1rq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/me/IdeaProjects/up/grafana/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/tv/xmlxs5hd45s0n4r0qs5jtlhnbgpkgq/T/pip-install-z1c97jsm/psycopg2/
    Complete output (151 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    ...
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework
...
I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/me/IdeaProjects/up/grafana/env/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
    psycopg/pqpath.c:138:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1717:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        ret = 1;
              ^
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1822:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/me/IdeaProjects/up/grafana/env/include -
...
I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/me/IdeaProjects/up/grafana/env/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g ...
L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64

    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/me/IdeaProjects/up/grafana/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/tv/xmlxs5hd45s0n4r0qs5jtlhnbgpkgq/T/pip-install-z1c97jsm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/tv/xmlxs5hd45s0n4r0qs5jtlhnbgpkgq/T/pip-install-z1c97jsm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/tv/xmlxs5hd45s0n4r0qs5jtlhnbgpkgq/T/pip-record-984vc1rq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/me/IdeaProjects/up/grafana/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Check your requirements.txt file. Does it include both `psycopg2` and `psycopg2-binary`? If so, remove psycopg2.

Comment: @Mercury I do that and then I have just `psycopg2-binary==2.8` left, but it fails with `No module named 'psycopg2'`, given my script has `import psycopg2`

Comment: That's strange. You should be able to import psycopg2 if psycopg2 binary is installed. Try a sanity check: by making a new virtual environment with `python3 -m venv env` -> `source env/bin/activate` -> `pip install --upgrade pip`, and then `pip install psycopg2-binary`. Then in this env, open up python and see if you can run `import psycopg2`.

Comment: Thanks I think that worked, just doing 'pip install psycopg2-binary'

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63592445/5320906).