# cmake suddenly doesn't work with updated Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake

I am desperate to solve this problem.  I have used cmake (3.18.2) and Xcode for years, but it suddenly has stopped working.  Have make the following simple setup:

I made a `main.cpp` file :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(untitled)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

I make a build file and in it I run:

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang - broken
CMake Error at /opt/anaconda3/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/bmetcalf/Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/local/bin/gmake cmTC_95f1f/fast && /usr/local/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_95f1f.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_95f1f.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/bmetcalf/Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_95f1f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang   -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /opt/anaconda3/include  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_95f1f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/bmetcalf/Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_95f1f
    /opt/anaconda3/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_95f1f.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /opt/anaconda3/include  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/opt/anaconda3/lib  CMakeFiles/cmTC_95f1f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_95f1f 
    ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
    clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_95f1f.dir/build.make:106: cmTC_95f1f] Error 1
    gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/bmetcalf/Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:140: cmTC_95f1f/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/bmetcalf/Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/bmetcalf/Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The cmake being used is from anaconda but this also happens with the homebrew cmake. Both are up to date.

I have installed the latest Xcode and commandline tools (v13.0) because this started with not being able to build an Xcode project, but this seems that this might be independent of
Xcode. I have tried resetting the Xcode paths with  `xcode-select --reset`, `xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`, `xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` etc. Non of this has helped. I've set the command line tools in Xcode preference->locations.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592445/ld-unsupported-tapi-file-type-tapi-tbd-in-yaml-file

as a suggestion, always look at what cmake outputs, cause it's super useful. always try running the commands it tried and see what you get

then try tweaking those commands to maybe fix your issue

Comment: Maybe the solution here helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592445/ld-unsupported-tapi-file-type-tapi-tbd-in-yaml-file

Comment: I followed the solution in  stackoverflow.com/questions/63592445/… including restarting the computer.  There is not change.  I've looked at the the cmake output, but I can't make much sense of it.  I don't understand why cmake can't be using the indigenous clang instead of the anaconda version.  It seems to have an error in test compiling some test program.

Comment: It appears that anaconda's cmake is no longer compatible with Xcode.  It uses the compilers from the cmake distribution which do not seem to work on the test file.

Comment: Apropos the condo-cmake-xcode problem  [link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/compiler-tools.html#macos-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of Anaconda resetting environmental variables so that their own build tools are used and not the ones in Xcode Command Line Tools.  These where compatible with building a an Xcode project with the cmake provided by Anaconda, but this is no longer the case.  You cannot even make a cmake from another source work because Anaconda will force it to use anaconda's tools as well.  It is difficult to reset all the necessary environmental variables or make Anaconda compatible with macOS 10.9 SDK or above (see [link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/compiler-tools.html#anaconda-compilers-implicitly-add-rpath-pointing-to-the-conda-environment) ) in a more permanent way.  Perhaps the interference with the system can be avoided using Conda environments somehow.  For me, anaconda interfering with you building your own programs defeats its purpose.

Comment: Is there some sample code you could share?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @simon.  I answered my own question so the code in the original question is mine.

Comment: If this solution worked for you could you mark it as accepted so it appears solved in the search

Comment: I don't see how to do that...

Comment: Below the Vote count you should see a greyed out arrow which you can, as the question creator, click on.