# How to work around the "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" error when running simple fortran files with the gfortran command?

Tags: gcc, compilation, homebrew, gfortran, arm64

I am running tests to see if the downloaded version of gfortran ([https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases](https://stackoverflow.com)) works after upgrading from Monterey to Sonoma.  The *gfortran* package is required for some work that I am doing in addition to *gcc* and *cpp*.  Only gfortran was not shown when running `which gfortran`.  The following commands for *gcc* and *cpp* yielded

`which gcc`

**/usr/bin/gcc**

`which cpp`

**/usr/bin/cpp**

To retrieve gfortran, I used the link above to download the .dmg. This resulted in gfortran being placed within the "**/usr/local/gfortran**" with a symbolic link to "**/usr/local/bin/gfortran**".  To run gfortran, I also had to download Xcode version 15.3 from the App Store and run `xcode-select --install` to add a *CommandLineTools* directory.  Inside that directory you see the following after running the command most recently referenced:

`ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/`

**MacOSX.sdk    MacOSX13.3.sdk  MacOSX13.sdk    MacOSX14.4.sdk  MacOSX14.sdk**

When I run gfortran on the following file I get this message:

`gfortran TEST_1_fortran_only_fixed.f`

**ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

I've seen references to these errors on forums, and I have been largely following suggestions outlined in those discussions which I will elaborate more on below.

I have tried what was recommended here:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592445/ld-unsupported-tapi-file-type-tapi-tbd-in-yaml-file](https://stackoverflow.com).  That required an installation of home-brew followed by upgrades to *gcc* and *llvm*.  Nothing is referenced in the compilation instructions about *llvm* for the work that I'm doing.  I did run `brew install llvm` just in case, however, followed by the appropriate upgrades to `gcc`.  Furthermore, I ran `setenv LIBRARY_PATH {$LIBRARY_PATH}:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/lib` as well as all other versions within the **/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/** directory to see if the error message above was reproduced.  It was.

The bulk of suggestions online does not seem to resolve the issue I'm having, and all the discussions of the issue follow very similar approaches.  What I can glean from the error message at this point is that the YAML file is not supported and that there is one error.  However, I also notice that part of the error message containing **for architecture arm64** may be important.  My MacBook Pro is a **Apple M1 Max**, and I wondered if this was the issue.  When looking at the gfortran version, I see the following information:

`gfortran -v`

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/gfortran/libexec/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin23/13.2.0/lto-wrapper
**Target: aarch64-apple-darwin23**
Configured with: ../gcc-13-branch/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gfortran --with-gmp=/Users/fx/devel/gcc/build_package/deps --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,jit,lto,objc,obj-c++ --build=aarch64-apple-darwin23 --with-system-zlib --with-**sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk**
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
**gcc version 13.2.0 (GCC)**

The **sysroot** references the *MacOSX.sdk*, so I decided to switch back to the original $LIBRARY_PATH containing *MacOSX.sdk*.  Furthermore, I see a reference to **aarch64**, which is the same thing as **arm64** from what I understand.  This doesn't help me.  The gcc version is also listed, which says

`gcc -v`

Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

The *gcc* version is apple clang version 15.0.0, but the *gcc* version referenced when running `gfortran -v` is 13.2.0.  I'm not sure if that is a problem or not.

**Other Information:**

1. **/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd** contains Targets and Symbols and has a list of dynamic libraries with extension .dylib.
2. There are discussions that mention a *mismatch between the linker and SDKs*.  I suspect that this may be the case, but I'm not sure yet.  I notice an ld referenced at the beginning of the error message.

I plan to continue to research online to see what I can find, but if anyone has some immediate insights that would be helpful at resolving this issue, that would be great.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What `ld` is gfortran calling out to? It can't be the one from Xcode...

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error message in this discussion:  https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722490.    Buried in this discussion is a nugget, one that lay hidden among the other suggestions I came across in this link here:  [Can't compile fortran on MacOS Monterey: ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74318052/cant-compile-fortran-on-macos-monterey-ld-unsupported-tapi-file-type-tapi-t).  Apparently I already had my conda environment activated when opening a fresh terminal window.  I needed to deactivate the conda environment to get past this error.  This error is now resolved and is the solution to the error above.